# How to bind event handler for custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am new to custom controls in asp.net. I am facing difficulty while attaching the click event handler for the image button. I written the following code for server control.

```
        ImageButton _imgbtn;
        TextBox txtOutput;
        Label _lblname;
        public ImageButton searchBtn
        {
            get { return _imgbtn; }
            set { _imgbtn = value; }
        }

        public Label lblName
        {
            get { return _lblname; }
            set { _lblname = value; }
        }
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
             txtOutput = new TextBox();
            txtOutput.Width = 180;
            txtOutput.ID = "ResultOutput";
            txtOutput.Enabled = false;
            Controls.Add(txtOutput);

            searchBtn = new ImageButton();
            Controls.Add(searchBtn);
            lblName = new Label();
            lblName.Text = "";
            Controls.Add(lblName);

        }
        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            //base.Render(output);
            txtOutput.RenderControl(output);
            searchBtn.RenderControl(output);
            lblName.RenderControl(output);
        }
```

I added this custom control to the .aspx page with register tag as follows.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mycontrol" Namespace="MyControl" Assembly="MyControl" %>
```

In aspx.cs file I give the property values as below,

```
        CustomControl mycustctrol;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                mycustctrol = myCust as CustomControl;
                mycustctrol.searchBtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/searchicon.png";
                mycustctrol.searchBtn.OnClientClick = "GenerateClickEvent"

            }
        }


public void GenerateClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        mycustctrol.lblName.Text = "clicked";
    }
```

After running this application I am getting the following error.

> 'GenerateClickEvent' is undefined

Where I done the mistake. I tried with declaring an event like `public event EventHandler GenerateClickEvent;`, but I am unable to go further. Can you please show me the way how to achieve this.

I also tried with the javascript function in the .aspx page as

```
function GenerateClickEvent() {

        alert('clicked');
    }
```

`alert('clicked');` is not firing.

Comment: GenerateClickEvent did you defined jacascript for this

Comment: Yes. See my edited question once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want something like this what you are doing is for client click

```
 mycustctrol.searchBtn.OnClientClick = "GenerateClickEvent()"
```

and something like this for the event click

```
 mycustctrol.searchBtn.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(GenerateClickEvent_Click);

 protected void GenerateClickEvent_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
  {
        mycustctrol.lblName.Text = "clicked";
  }
```

Comment: For javascript it is working fine. But for event it is giving the following error. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler'`while compilation

Comment: Is it correct way to bind the event in `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` condition?

Comment: If I write the binding event and customcontrol object outside the if condition in page load, it is working fine.

Comment: ohhhh do not use it the way you have it you are not posting back on load in your case

Comment: I am not understood. Is it better to write in `if` condition or outside the `if` condition?

Comment: in your case it better  outside the if condition